# cudaMemcpy - copy an int from host to device error

Tags: cuda

What is the difference between

```
 cudaMemcpy and cudaMemset??
```

How can I copy an int value from host to device?
This is the code I am using

```
int addXdir = 1;
int devAddXdir;
cudaMalloc((void**)&devAddXdir, sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(devAddXdir, addXdir, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

it gives the following errors
    error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"
    error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *"

Comment: The difference between cudaMemcpy and cudaMemset is that one takes a value as the source, the other a pointer. This difference is made perfectly clear in the API documentation of the two functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`devAddXdir` must be a pointer for that code to work. Also, you must pass `addXdir` by reference to `cudaMemcpy`, not by value. Like this:

```
int addXdir = 1;
int * devAddXdir;
cudaMalloc((void**)&devAddXdir, sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(devAddXdir, &addXdir, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```